# Cisco RV042 Port Forwarding

Tags: cisco, router

We have an application server that our company's branches connect to. Right now, they can connect because the E.R.P app developer configured our main router for port forwarding. They connect by typing `1.1.1.1:9001/forms/servlet` into a web browser. 1.1.1.1 is the router's interface connected to the ISP (1.1.1.1 made up).

Our internal subnet is on the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet, the server in question is 192.168.1.25. We have 2 ISPs connected to 2 different routers, one is for backup in case the primary goes down. I want to configure the backup router (Cisco RV042) for port forwarding but I am a bit confused regarding which ports and addresses to use.

Assume 2.2.2.2 is the IP address of the second router's interface connected to the ISP. How would I forward this to my application server?

Comment: Can you give your private IP range and what IP/port the application server is listening on?

Comment: We are using the 192.168.1.0 /24 subnet and the app server is 192.168.1.25. its listening on port 9001.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're doing any complex port forwarding with this setup.  All you need to do is specify a private IP address for inbound requests to port 9001 to head to.

```
  2.2.2.2:9001 --------> 192.168.1.25:9001
```

You can access the port forwarding options on the RV042, under Setup > Forwarding

Check out the full [RV042 Manual](http://s3.amazonaws.com/szmanuals/5890c9cc77fda234e2a0d7c5efb8f877) for more information, page 14 has more info on Port Forwarding.

Comment: thanks very much for the prompt reply. i really appreciate ur help. correct me if im wrong, the traffic originates from our branches with a source port of 80 (http) and a destination port of 9001 ? if that's true, isnt 80 supposed to be somewhere in the forwarding statement ??

Comment: No, based on your OP; `1.1.1.1:9001/forms/servlet` signifies that your trying to connect to 1.1.1.1 on port 9001. Verify that your application server **is** listening on port 9001. Linux would be `lsof -i -n`. If you're listening on port 80, let me know so I can modify the answer accordingly.

Comment: Honestly, i don't really know the port the server is listening on. I just guessed that since our branch offices had to type http://1.1.1.1:9001/forms/frmservlet into a web browser to gain access, then its 9001.

Comment: @dennix2014 That's fairly common if you're hosting multiple servers on your network that are all expecting HTTP connections. Go to the server that's hosting the service, and figure out what ports are open and listening.

Comment: Thanks Fizzle for all your help. i found out that the app is listening on port 9001.

Comment: These are the fields on the forward page of the router: 1.Port range Forwarding. 1A. Service (the default is "all traffic tcp and udp 1-65534). 1B. Ip address......................... 1C. enable (check box) 1D. Add to list. 2. Port triggering. 2A. application name....... 2B. Trigger port range .....to....... 2C. Incoming port range .......to.......... 2D. Add to list. Any idea?

Comment: @dennix2014 It's a 1:1 mapping. 1A) You need to do service management and define your own service.  Service Name - something locally significant (e.g. LOCALHTTP); Protocol - HTTP; Port Range - 9001. 1B) 192.168.1.25 1C) Enable (CHECK). 2A) something local (e.g. LOCALHTTP). 2B) 9001 2C) 9001. Let me know how that works out for you.

Comment: Ok. just configured it. Will check it out on Saturday and then get back to you. Thanks very very much. You have been very kind.

Comment: I didnt wait till Saturday, just tested it and it works like a charm. Thanks Fizzle.

Comment: emm.....i dont see any check box next to any answer??